# Insert rows at specific index of another row in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here's the code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="param in tags[$index].parameters">
            <td class="previewParamName">{{param.name}}</td>
            <td>
                <div ng-if="is_array(param)">
                    <div class="previewParamValue limitWidth">List <span class="arrayParamArrow" ng-click="showArrayParams(param)" ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down': !arrayCollapsed, 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up': arrayCollapsed}"></span></div>
                </div>
                <div ng-if="!is_array(param)">
                    <div class="previewParamValue" tooltip-placement="bottom" tooltip="{{param.value}}" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter">{{param.value | limitTo : 25}}</div>
                </div>
            </td>
</tr>
<tr ng-hide="!arrayCollapsed" ng-repeat="params in arrayParameter">
      <td>{{params.name}}</td>
      <td class="wordBreak">{{params.value}}</td>
</tr>
```

What i want is to be able to put second row ng-repeat below specific row in the first ng-repeat, specifically when ng-if=is_array(param) div is shown, because it indicates that there needs to be more sub rows for that one specific row. Thanks

Comment: How are `arrayParameter` and `tags[$index].parameters` related?

Comment: arrayParameter array is populated on click ng-click="showArrayParams(param)" where param is current parameter in tags[$index].parameters.

Comment: It would help if you posted your array structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the exact structure for your array and how you get params for rows on click. But to render it you should try to use `ngRepeatStart` and `ngRepeatEnd` directives.

Something like this (simplified a little for the demo):

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="param in tags.parameters" ng-init="param.arrayCollapsed = false">
    <td class="previewParamName">{{param.name}}</td>
    <td>
        <div ng-if="is_array(param)">
            <div class="previewParamValue limitWidth" ng-click="param.arrayCollapsed = !param.arrayCollapsed">
                List <span class="arrayParamArrow" ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down': !arrayCollapsed, 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up': arrayCollapsed}"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="!is_array(param)">
            <div class="previewParamValue" tooltip-placement="bottom" tooltip="{{param.value}}" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter">{{param.value | limitTo : 25}}</div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="p in param" ng-show="param.arrayCollapsed" class="params-row">
    <td>{{p.name}}</td>
    <td class="wordBreak">{{p.value}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end></tr>
```

From here you should be able to adjust it for your code.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/tW3rUYXqoM9fTNHdOf9K?p=info

---

### UPD: Better solution

Original code contains problem is that `ngRepeatEnd` `tr` is repeated for each iteration creating bunch of unnecessary empty `tr`. Not good.

Below is more more straightforward solution which uses two repeaters: one on `tbody` and the second on inner `tr`. Multiple tbodies is perfectly valid and it's even feels good that parameter rows are grouped together with their parent row into the same `tbody`.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
    <tbody ng-repeat="param in tags.parameters" ng-init="param.arrayCollapsed = false">
        <tr>
            <td class="previewParamName">{{param.name}}</td>
            <td>
                <div ng-if="is_array(param)">
                    <div class="previewParamValue limitWidth" ng-click="param.arrayCollapsed = !param.arrayCollapsed">
                        List <span class="arrayParamArrow" ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down': !arrayCollapsed, 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up': arrayCollapsed}"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div ng-if="!is_array(param)">
                    <div class="previewParamValue" tooltip-placement="bottom" tooltip="{{param.value}}" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter">{{param.value | limitTo : 25}}</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-if="is_array(param)" ng-repeat="p in param" ng-show="param.arrayCollapsed" class="params-row">
            <td>{{p.name}}</td>
            <td class="wordBreak">{{p.value}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/0V1hDOpl2wukKFeIZC1O?p=info

Comment: Thanks, this helped me solve the issue, didn't know about ng-repeat-start/end, useful thing.

Comment: I found a problem with my original code. Check fixed solution, which I think is better.